# Problem in Apache Error Log?

Tags: apache2, php, logging

**I'm new to PHP and UBUNTU,**

First of all, I'll install the **wine windows program loader** and download the **Macro-media Dreamwear**. before a day it working fine but yesterday it had some problem.

1. I'll create the program of **`PhpTest.php`**  and run the application **`http://localhost/Test/PhpTest.php`** in Firefox its running fine in my view.
2. Some times it had an error means I'll check the **`error.log`** and correct it. **(location: /var/log/apache2/error.log)**
3. But yesterday the **`error.log`** is continuously running. its says same error.

   > [Thu Jul 24 16:13:49.856537 2014] [:error] [pid 1843] [client 127.0.0.1:44200] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 9443 in /var/www/html/Test/PhpTest.php on line 118
4. I'll check to close all the programs like **Macro-media Dreamwear and Firefox**. But its still running same error is running.
5. After I'll check all kind of place in running path in this place automatically creating some folder and inside the file is looking like as same the **folder is `_notes`** and **file is `PhpTest.php.mno`** file location **`(/var/www/html/Test/_notes/PhpTest.php.mno)`.**

[image: **PhpTest.php.mno file is look like**]

8. I'll completely Remove the folder and file But still error.log file is throwing in same error.

Comment: Seems like you just have an undefined offset on line 118...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, all of them fine, And got solution for this problem,

I've Completely Remove this file **`PhpTest.php.mno`** and I'll check its continue same error only occur, Then after I'll `SHUTDOWN` my system  and start after nearby 5 hours it working fine.

> /var/www/html/Test/_notes/PhpTest.php.mno